# Iterating thru a JSON object after an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Have and php/mySql/jquery application.  This application gets a json string of any array of table row contents and Jquery should loop thru the object and append each row to the primary table.  The rows counts can vary.

The problem is the $.each only iterates thru the first row of the object.

To get the row(s) I make the following AJAX call.

```
 `$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "se_races_ajax.php",
  data: {act: 'addPass', pass_id:pid, ryr: ryr, yr: yr, sid: series_id},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (dataret) {
        $.each(dataret, function (key, value) {
             if (value.response.status !== 'success') {
                        ajax_failure(value)
             } else {
                 if (key.startsWith('addPass')) {
                 $('#raceList tbody').append(value.response.trContent);
                 }
             }
         })
       }
 })`
```

This returns the following JSON data.(I have removed the actual trContent(table row html) data to keep this readable.

```
{
  "addPass0": {
    "response": {
      "status": "success",
      "data": null,
      "id": 2496,
      "rows": null,
      "system": "alpha"
    }
  },
  "addPass1": {
    "response": {
      "status": "success",
      "data": null,
      "id": 2497,
      "rows": null,
      "system": "alpha"
    }
  },
  "addPass2": {
    "response": {
      "status": "success",
      "data": null,
      "id": 2498,
      "rows": null,
      "system": "alpha"
    }
  }
}
```

I think it must be some formatting of JSON or the something about the Object conversion in JSON.
This may be a clue  here is the preview view of the Network XHR in chrome dev tools,  It seems to imply some higher level nesting.

[image]

One second possible clue is that when in a break point inside the $.each when I look at the value of dataret it says dataret is not defined.  Could something be messing with it?

If this helps shed any light here is the print_r of the PHP array that is then encoded with json_encode($array) and echoed;

Array ( [addPass0] => Array ( [response] => Array ( [status] => success [data] => [id] => 2499 [rows] => [query] => INSERT IGNORE INTO series_race_list (series_id,series_year,event_id,race_num,id) VALUES('116','2019','6','99','') [system] => alpha ) ) [addPass1] => Array ( [response] => Array ( [status] => success [data] => [id] => 2500 [rows] => [query] => INSERT IGNORE INTO series_race_list (series_id,series_year,event_id,race_num,id) VALUES('116','2019','378','99','') [system] => alpha ) ) [addPass2] => Array ( [response] => Array ( [status] => success [data] => [id] => 2501 [rows] => [query] => INSERT IGNORE INTO series_race_list (series_id,series_year,event_id,race_num,id) VALUES('116','2019','379','99','') [system] => alpha ) ) )

Thanks in advance for any help.
Dave

Comment: It runs just fine with the data you posted in. I added console.log(key) in the loop. It printed all three.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything wrong with it at first glance either.   Here's a jsfiddle.   https://jsfiddle.net/6w5qm7bt/2/. That just has the JSON inline as a variable.  So it might be some way that your php file is formatting the JSON or something.   It's hard to test without access to your php, but you might try making the JSON a hard coded file and load it via AJAX, just for debugging purposes.  And then if it works with hard coded JSON, compare what the dev tools show you for the AJAX response between the two...

Comment: Will try the hard coded JSON didn't think of that.

Comment: Would seeing the print_r of the the array that is being encoded in PHP give any clues.

Comment: I didn't the console log and saw the same thing.  off in another direction Thanks